# ColumnName_main+low_sample ColumnName_x005c__x0027_sample appears in CSV file result of SQL query in Logic App

Tags: sql-server, azure-logic-apps, azure-synapse

I have a Azure Logic App in which I am executing the SQL Select queries and converting the output of SQL Queries in CSV files and Mail them. The SQL view contains column names with special characters such as **[+,%,() or whitespaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2Iny.png)**. But after creating the CSV file from the Query result the column are replaced with unknown values in place of special characters. Example -
a column name **"total(value + value)"** is replace in CSV with 
**"total_x005c_value_x0027_value_x005c_"**. Please help me with this I want the exact column names in CSV file also.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You get this it is because the source data in sql server is UCS-2. And in logic app it doesn't support to decode it.

The simplest way is set the custom header when you create the csv table.

[image]

[image]

However if you have multiple columns it will be hard to solve it. So you could use Azure Function to convert the json data. You pass the data to HTTP trigger Function, convert it and return data to the logic app and create the CSV.